# Why values are not displayed for some columns of an ALV List?

Tags: abap

I am trying to create an ALV report with list display but some of the contents are not displaying in the output list. I created a classical report and an ALV report with grid display and I was successful. But this list display is creating a problem.

I've included the `REUSE_ALV_LIST_DISPLAY` function, with the right internal table name. I've debugged and all my data is coming in the final internal table correctly but it is not displaying in output list:

[image]

Here is my code (note that the flight demo data is to be generated via the program `SAPBC_DATA_GENERATOR`, once):

```
REPORT ztest.

SELECT scarr~carrid, spfli~connid
  FROM scarr INNER JOIN spfli ON scarr~carrid = spfli~carrid
  INTO TABLE @DATA(it_f).

DATA(it_fcat) = VALUE slis_t_fieldcat_alv(
  ( tabname   = 'SCARR'
    fieldname = 'CARRID'
    seltext_l = 'Carrier code'
    col_pos   = 1
    outputlen = 20 )
  ( tabname   = 'SPFLI'
    fieldname = 'CONNID'
    seltext_l = 'Connection ID'
    col_pos   = 2
    outputlen = 20 ) ).

CALL FUNCTION 'REUSE_ALV_LIST_DISPLAY'
  EXPORTING
    it_fieldcat = it_fcat
  TABLES
    t_outtab    = it_f.
```

Comment: It seems that all columns with TABNAME = 'ZINT_PRS_MST' have the issue, even "First name" which displays a weird value (maybe it's because it appears like a key ALV column). Did you try to change it? By the way, why don't you use the class `CL_SALV_TABLE` in List mode, so that to avoid defining the ALV catalog?

Comment: Thank you sandra. The situation is I am a complete noob in abap and I dont know how to do it. Could you please guide me. Thank you.

Comment: There are many examples in the web, including references to SAP demo programs.

Comment: I used the class CL_SALV_TABLE in list mode and it worked. Thank you so much. But my question is why REUSE_ALV_LIST_DISPLAY function module not working.

Comment: Apart CL_SALV_TABLE, I also gave a big clue that you didn't see, I guess. I could move it to an answer though.

Comment: Try to use `INTO CORRESPONDING FIELDS` everywhere in selects, it seems your tabular data are messed during itab fill

Comment: For information, I have edited the question thoroughly to provide a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) which may be easily checked by future visitors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a simple ALV table, you don't have to fill the component `TABNAME` of the field catalog. `TABNAME` is only needed for the hierarchical-sequential lists (function module `REUSE_ALV_HIERSEQ_LIST_DISPLAY` for instance) which are an output of two tables.

If you omit it, or if you give the same value (any value) for all columns, you will get a correct output:

[image]

Code with the correction:

```
SELECT scarr~carrid, spfli~connid
  FROM scarr INNER JOIN spfli ON scarr~carrid = spfli~carrid
  INTO TABLE @DATA(it_f).

DATA(it_fcat) = VALUE slis_t_fieldcat_alv(
  ( " do not fill TABNAME // tabname   = 'SCARR'
    fieldname = 'CARRID'
    seltext_l = 'Carrier code'
    col_pos   = 1
    outputlen = 20 )
  ( " do not fill TABNAME // tabname   = 'SPFLI'
    fieldname = 'CONNID'
    seltext_l = 'Connection ID'
    col_pos   = 2
    outputlen = 20 ) ).

CALL FUNCTION 'REUSE_ALV_LIST_DISPLAY'
  EXPORTING
    it_fieldcat = it_fcat
  TABLES
    t_outtab    = it_f.
```

Answer (score -2):

EDIT: I see that you two already solved the problem in comments.

As Sandra wrote, you could try using cl_salv_table. It should look like this:

```
  cl_salv_table=>factory(
*  EXPORTING
*    list_display   = if_salv_c_bool_sap=>true
*    r_container    =
*    container_name =
    IMPORTING
      r_salv_table   = DATA(lr_alv)
   CHANGING
      t_table        = it_f
  ).

  lr_alv->display( ).
```

Comment: I think it doesn't answer the question ("Why values are not displayed for some columns of an ALV List?"), as the OP said. Remember that stackoverflow is not a help forum, it's a Question & Answer forum (cf Tour and Help). If people look for personal help, then SCN forum is perfect for that.

Comment: So... Next time should I copy your comment(where you suggest cl_salv_table and OP asks for code) and add mine to yours? 

Also thx for the reply. Sadly I'm not used to posting stuff in the Internet.

Comment: My opinion: it was important to mention `cl_salv_table` at least once (and only as a comment) because the OP used an obsolete technology, but no need to mention more, internet contains lots of working examples, no need to repeat, and in case of issue, the OP might ask a new question specific to cl_salv_table. You may even delete your own question (or any comment) if you feel it has no added value (I already did it in the past for my own answers and comments).

Comment: Thanks for your time and answers :)